# lift `??` construct

Tags: scala, lift

I have browsed lift's [MegaProtoUser](http://scala-tools.org/scaladocs/liftweb/1.0/net/liftweb/mapper/ProtoUser.scala.html#Some(32)) and encountered this construction: `??("Last Name")`. Can anyone explain, what that means?
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined on object `S`:

```
def ??(str : String)
```

> Get a core lift localized string or return the original string [details]